# Should search engines ignore related question titles?

Tags: discussion, search, related-questions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Google Search should not index “Related questions” lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/google-search-should-not-index-related-questions-lists)

When I run a Google query for ["site:stackoverflow.com cakephp +testaction redirect"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+cakephp+%2Btestaction+redirect), I get a bunch of pages, but most of them only have testaction as part of a related question:
[How to pass querystring to testAction in CakePHP 1.2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200925/how-to-pass-querystring-to-testaction-in-cakephp-1-2)

I find this frustrating, because it looks like my search results are being polluted with irrelevant results.

I have three questions:

1. Is it possible to make search engines ignore the related questions section on the page or give it less weight?
2. Is there some benefit to the search engines treating the related question titles as part of the page? (E.g., I search using terms that are related, but don't otherwise appear on a page that would really help me.)
3. The reason I'm using Google instead of the Stack Overflow search is that I can specify a search term as required. Any way to do that in Stack Overflow search?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the site could load the related questions section as an AJAX call. That way the static page just contains the core content, and the search engines wouldn't see the related questions.

It might be a performance problem, though. It doesn't seem like the Stack Overflow style.

Answer (score 0):

I did a little research and found that Yahoo supports the [robots-nocontent](http://help.yahoo.com/l/us/yahoo/search/indexing/slurp-14.html) class, but Google doesn't. Google supports [AdSense section targeting](https://www.google.com/adsense/support/bin/answer.py?answer=23168) but there's no indication that it affects search results.

Answer (score 0):

> The reason I'm using Google instead of the Stack Overflow search is that I can specify a search term as required. Any way to do that in Stack Overflow search?

I don't know what "specify a search term as required means", but ...

https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

> search engines treating the related question titles as part of the page?

Most relevant results are at the top, as those results have the word in the title or primary areas of the page. Where the search term appears on the page affects the result order.

Seems correct to me.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's incorrect, just slightly frustrating. I completely agree with Justin Grant's answer:
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/google-search-should-not-index-related-questions-lists/30686#30686

As for specifying a search term as required, I was slightly confused. I thought +foo meant any Google results must include the word foo. That's wrong according to this page:

http://www.google.com/support/websearch/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=136861

I'll do some more search comparisons and post on the duplicate question you linked to.