# The "Related" list on a question page skews Google indexing

Tags: feature-request, google, related-questions, search-indexing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Google Search should not index “Related questions” lists](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/google-search-should-not-index-related-questions-lists)

Noticed this when I searched for "jquery flash detection". The second result on Google was [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/159261/cross-browser-flash-detection-in-javascript), which mentioned nothing about jquery. However jquery happened to be in the related questions list on the bottom right. This is not a big deal, but you guys may want to generate the related list via JavaScript to get around this problem.