# Why Related links have no "nofollow" attribute

Tags: discussion, search, linked-questions, search-engine

I noticed that the links at the right of any stackoveflow.com pages lacks "nofollow" attribute. CMIIW, but these links is result of algorithm work that compares question based on automatic text comparison. This means that unless search engine specifically tracks this case, the links works as reputation amplifier and get bigger pagerank or equivalent value if it's not Google. The consequence of this is from the search engine point of view a question linked  manually from other SO questions (by humans) N times and question appearing N times on Related section ("handpicked by the computer") have similar chances to appear on the first search results page. But a search engine always tries to favor human choices for obvious reasons.

Comment: So what's the problem then?

Comment: I thought than in order to be more "search engine" friendly, SE should add "nofollow" for such links. I may interpret some technical details wrongly, but imho when this is done, more great question/answer will appear on Google results pages.

Comment: Ok - there's some debate as to whether that helps or hurts; see: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/26145/google-search-should-not-index-related-questions-lists/26275#26275

Comment: @Shog9 I think these questions are asking about different things. This one is concerned with the rank of the *link targets* benefiting unfairly by being linked from "related" pages, that one is concerned about the linking page being associated with keywords from the related question titles which are not present in the question itself.